# Magento 1.9.2 Installation stuck on Configuration

Tags: magento, xampp, installation, localhost, wamp

I've tried every solution on this website and others, unfortunately nothing is working.  I click continue on the "Configuration" page and it processes for a minute or two and then reloads the configuration page.  I would assume it was timing out but it always takes different lengths of time.

I've tried installing on XAMPP, WAMP and a Vagrant VM machine but they all have the same issue.

The only thing I can think of is that it is related to the default ports.  I'm usings ports like 3305 and 4447 because 80/8080 are taken on my work computer by IIS.

Is there an issue using the port suffix when creating magento installations?

I'm using php 5.5.12, according to Mage 1.9.2 documentation PHP 5.5 is required a minimum.

Things I've tried:

- Switching between "localhost" and "127.0.0.1" with the various ports on the end
- Removing the validation class from the base URL box
- Checking "Skip Base URL Validation Before the Next Step"
- Trying various URLs in the hosts file

There's also some other really specific things I tried that I can't quite recall because I've tried so much over the past 4 hours, but pretty much if it's suggested on this site or the Magento forums then I've already done it.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are tables installed?

Comment: Yes, I installed the 1.9.2 sample data in a table called 'magento'

Comment: Please..... Its database, Not table :(  Thats is the problem. You just create one more database and continue installation again.

Comment: Sorry, bad wording on my part, I created a database called 'magento'